# While executing case when both when and else part is working in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have used case when in select query and it executing both when and else part. please give a solution to come out of this.

```
 SELECT column2
  FROM template_Data_Details_bkp
 WHERE     template_id = (SELECT template_id
                            FROM templates
                           WHERE template_name = 'Testing')
       AND column1 = 'EM1'
       AND (CASE
               WHEN (column2 = 'stock' AND column1 = 'EM1')
               THEN
                  column2
               ELSE
                  (SELECT column2
                     FROM template_data_details_bkp
                    WHERE     template_id =
                                 (SELECT template_id
                                    FROM templates
                                   WHERE template_name = 'Testing')
                          AND column1 = 'EM1'
                          AND column4 = 'YES')
            END) = column2;
```

The Table looks like

| column1 | column2 | column4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EM1 | stock | NO |
| EM1 | ragavi | YES |

I excepting column2 value- stock,
but it returns both the values

Comment: It's not that clear to me. Can you please better explain the issue? Are you having an unexpected result, an error, ... ? Also, can you please post sample data for all the involved tables?

Comment: The excepted result - 1st row in Table
Actual Result - Getting both rows

Comment: Without knowing the content of the involved tables, the only thing we know is that your where condition matches two rows instead of just one, as you expected, but it's quite impossible to understand why

Comment: In this particular case the result of your where condition will be: where column1 = 'EM1' and column2 = column2, so you will get two rows in your result set.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have two rows.

In the first row, the case statement enters into `WHEN (column2 = 'stock' AND column1 = 'EM1')`
In the second row, the statement enters into `ELSE`

You have one result per row.

If you want to see just one row, skip the else statement, or clean your WHERE statement and make it easier.

Regards.